# Issues iterating through JSON list in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, json, for-loop

I have a file with JSON data in it, like so:

```
{
    "Results": [
            {"Id": "001",
            "Name": "Bob",
            "Items": {
                "Cars": "1",
                "Books": "3",
                "Phones": "1"}
            },

            {"Id": "002",
            "Name": "Tom",
            "Items": {
                "Cars": "1",
                "Books": "3",
                "Phones": "1"}
            },

            {"Id": "003",
            "Name": "Sally",
            "Items": {
                "Cars": "1",
                "Books": "3",
                "Phones": "1"}
            }]
}
```

I can not figure out how to properly loop through the JSON. I would like to loop through the data and get a Name with the Cars for each member in the dataset. How can I accomplish this?

```
import json

with open('data.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

print data["Results"][0]["Name"] # Gives me a name for the first entry
print data["Results"][0]["Items"]["Cars"] # Gives me the number of cars for the first entry
```

I have tried looping through them with:

```
for i in data["Results"]:
print data["Results"][i]["Name"]
```

But recieve an error:
**TypeError: list indices must be integers, not dict**

Comment: `for i in data["Results"]: i["Name"]`

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you want: `{person['Name']: person['Items']['Cars'] for person in data["Results"]}`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You are assuming that `i` is an index, but it is a dictionary, use:

```
for item in data["Results"]:
    print item["Name"]
```

Quote from the [for Statements](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements):

> The for statement in Python differs a bit from what you may be used to in C or Pascal. Rather than always iterating over an arithmetic progression of numbers (like in Pascal), or giving the user the ability to define both the iteration step and halting condition (as C), *Python’s for statement iterates over the items of any sequence (a list or a string), in the order that they appear in the sequence*.

Comment: That makes sense now, thanks for your quick reply!! 

I am still unsure how I would loop through the sub-object for each one though?

Comment: @Bajan sure, assuming you mean the `Items` dictionary: `for key, value in item["Items"].iteritems():`. Please see the related topics: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops-in-python.

Comment: You are quick!

I got it done by using this:
`for item in data["Results"]:        print item["Items"]["Cars"]`

Which would be the recommended method?

Answer (score 7):

you are iterating through the dictionary not indexes so you should either use.

```
for item in data["Results"]:
    print item["Name"]
```

or

```
for i in range(len(data["Results"])):
    print data["Results"][i]["Name"]
```

Answer (score 5):

The confusion is in how dictionaries and lists are used in iteration.
A dictionary will iterate over it's keys (which you use as indices to get corresponding values)

```
x = {"a":3,  "b":4,  "c":5}
for key in x:   #same thing as using x.keys()
   print(key,x[key]) 

for value in x.values():
    print(value)      #this is better if the keys are irrelevant     

for key,value in x.items(): #this gives you both
    print(key,value)
```

but the default behaviour of iterating over a list will give you the elements instead of the indices:

```
y = [1,2,3,4]
for i in range(len(y)):  #iterate over the indices
    print(i,y[i])

for item in y:
    print(item)  #doesn't keep track of indices

for i,item in enumerate(y): #this gives you both
    print(i,item)
```

If you want to generalize your program to handle both types the same way you could use one of these functions:

```
def indices(obj):
    if isinstance(obj,dict):
        return obj.keys()
    elif isinstance(obj,list):
        return range(len(obj))
    else:
        raise TypeError("expected dict or list, got %r"%type(obj))

def values(obj):
    if isinstance(obj,dict):
        return obj.values()
    elif isinstance(obj,list):
        return obj
    else:
        raise TypeError("expected dict or list, got %r"%type(obj))

def enum(obj):
    if isinstance(obj,dict):
        return obj.items()
    elif isinstance(obj,list):
        return enumerate(obj)
    else:
        raise TypeError("expected dict or list, got %r"%type(obj))
```

this way if you, for example, later changed the json to store the results in a dict using the id as keys the program would still iterate through it the same way:

```
#data = <LOAD JSON>
for item in values(data["Results"]):
    print(item["name"])

#or
for i in indices(data["Results"]):
    print(data["Results"][i]["name"])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for json_data in data['Results']:
    for attribute, value in json_data.iteritems():
        print attribute, value # example usage
```