# Loop through array of json objects

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

What is the correct way to loop through the following json object?

```
test = [{
    'start': 'ieo5',
    'end': 'tiu9',
    'chain': 10489
}, {
    'start': 'qvc5',
    'end': 'tiu9',
    'chain': 45214
}, {
    'start': 'ieo5',
    'end': 'tiu9',
    'chain': 69296
}]
```

I essentially want to loop through and print out whatever the value of `start` is.

I've tried a bunch of options like the ones listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34951448/4912604) but can't seem to get it to work.

This doesn't work:

```
for x in test
    print x['start']
```

Comment: Use `print(x['start'])` instead. Python 3 needs parentheses in  `print` calls.

Comment: Also, `:` at the end of `for` line.

Comment: add column(:) after test in for loop statement

Comment: What you have there is not a JSON array. It is a Python structure of a list of dictionaries.

Comment: @LijoJose ? typo :D, "colon" not "column" :-)

Comment: :), yes you are correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code logic works fine, just few things making it not work:

- Since the tag is [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x), `print` needs to be called.
- Need colon after for line.

So the code would look like:

```
for x in test:
    print(x['start'])
```

Answer (score 1):

worked for me!

```
for d in test:
     print d['start']
```

> OP:
>
> ```
> ieo5
> qvc5
> ieo5
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is right just add a colon after the for statement

```
for x in test:
    print(x['start'])
```